# Autogenerating values for child/sub-documents in a collection within a MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb

My MongoDB collection has documents that can each contain an array of child documents. Each child document needs a way for me to uniquely identify it so that I can replace it or update it later.

How do I tell MongoDB to generate a unique value for each child document within the set?

I'm using the C# MongoDB driver.

```
{
    _id: 'gd37dg67dg63782gd78',
    name: 'foo'
    docs: [
        {
            idvalue: 'autogenerated',
            y: 10
        },
        {
            idvalue: 'autogenerated',
            y: 10
        },
        {
            idvalue: 'autogenerated',
            y: 10
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Isn't the index of the document kinda like an ID ?

Comment: Just pasted a sample to demonstrate what I'm asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB itself won't do that for you, but you can do what many document mappers do for subdocuments and assign them `ObjectId` values before you save them. This will get you a new, and unique-enough value for each of those fields from the C# driver:

```
ObjectId.GenerateNewId()
```

If you're using a document mapper, look and see how well it supports "nested documents". There's a good chance it will do this for you with little effort.

Comment: I know that the django nonrel fork handles this for you with embedded models. So i would think other drivers would too

Comment: The C# driver does not do this automatically.  A custom IBsonSerializer could be written to do this if one was so inclined.